# Putting Multiple Web Components Classes Into One Library

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'd like to define multiple web webcomponents inside one library. Like this:

```
library myapp;

import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

class Component1 extends WebComponent {
  int count = 0;
  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}

class Component2 extends WebComponent {
  int count = 0;
  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

And then use them in a html file like this:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="myapp.dart"></script>

<element name="x-component1" constructor="Component1" extends="div">
  <template>
    <button on-click="increment()">Click me</button>
    <span>(click count: {{count}})</span>
  </template>
</element>

<element name="x-component2" constructor="Component2" extends="div">
  <template>
    <button on-click="increment()">Click me</button>
    <span>(click count: {{count}})</span>
  </template>
</element>

<div is="x-component1"></div>
<div is="x-component2"></div>
```

When I'm trying to run this program I'm getting:

No constructor 'Component1.forElement' declared in class 'Component1'.

My Question:

Is there a way to put multiple web component classes into one library? Cause it looks like right now every web component class must be defined in its own library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to make this work at the moment. I opened: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/389 to track the bug.